# How to convert internal table of type LISTZEILE into JSON or XML?

Tags: json, xml, abap, sap-erp, sap-gateway

I have a requirement where in I have to expose Standard SAP reports to Gateway services.

So I have utilized INST_EXECUTE_REPORT function module and output of the above FM with 'RM06ELLB' as input is as follows:
[image]

[image]

The above image displays as in the gateway output.

Is there any way that I can convert the above ZEILE fields into a formatted json or xml structure like this:

```
 "zeile" : { "Material" : "100-120" , "Plant" : "1000" }
```

Answer (score 0):

The field of ZEILE looks like containing a formatted text. You can parse the line using ABAP SPLIT operator and put the parsed data into a structure. You can use the next static method after that:

```
  /ui2/cl_json=>serialize(
    exporting
      data        = lt_data
      pretty_name = /ui2/cl_json=>pretty_mode-camel_case
    receiving
      r_json      = lf_json
  ).
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.

But the above method is converting whole ZEILE line to json.                  I need to convert based on the fields of ZEILE.

Regards,

Arpitha

Comment: @Arpitha, didn't get your idea. What do you need in your output? It seems Skalozub module does exactly what you want. You need a set of dictionaries or a single dictionary with all ZEILE lines (material + plant)?